# Hide div tag using function

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I have two JSP pages. The first JSP page I have, in div, and another JSP page I am calling through a function. When I click select flow in 'S' I have to hide this div, otherwise not.

```html
<script>
  function sendValue(s) {
    window.returnValue = s;

    var value = s.split('|');
    var flowId = value[0];

    window.opener.setAccValue(s, "flowId", "credAcc", "debtAcc");

    //creditDebitRow(flowId);
  }
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#2F96C6">
  <TABLE class="picklist_tab" ALIGN=CENTER WIDTH="100%" border="0" bordercolor="black" cellpadding=5>
    <caption class='picklist_caption'>Fund List</caption>
    <TR>
      <TH class="picklist_th">Flow Id</TH>
      <TH class="picklist_th">Flow Id Name</TH>
      <TH class="picklist_th">Credit Acc. No.</TH>
      <TH class="picklist_th">Debit Acc. No.</TH>

      <%
         /* String flowId = request.getParameter("param1");
         flowId = flowId.trim(); */
         String query = "select flow_id, CR_ACC_NO, DR_ACC_NO, FLOW_ID_NAME from accountmaster ";
         query += "where active_status = 'Y' and VERIFIED_BY is not null"; // no need of flowId here
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

         while (rs.next()) {

       %>

        <TR>
          <TD class='picklist_td1' ALIGN="center"><a class='picklist_anchor' target=_self href='#' оnClick="javascript:sendValue('<%=(rs.getString(1))%>|<%=(rs.getString(2))%>|<%=(rs.getString(3))%>')"><%=(rs.getString(1))%></a></TD>
          <TD class='picklist_td2' ALIGN="left"><%=(rs.getString(4))%></TD>
          <TD class='picklist_td2' ALIGN="left"><%=(rs.getString(2))%></TD>
          <TD class='picklist_td2' ALIGN="left"><%=(rs.getString(3))%></TD>
        </TR>
      <%
       }
      %>

  </TABLE>

  <TABLE align=center width='80%'>
    <TR>
      <TD align='center'><input type='Button' value='BACK' оnclick='javascript:window.close()' /></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <BR>
</BODY>
```

```html
<div id="creditDebitRow" >
<TABLE border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="WIDTH: 100%;">
  <TR>
    <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>

    <TD class="lblText" width="10%">Credit Account</TD>
    
    <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" class="textBox" NAME="credAcc" id="credAcc" disabled></TD>

    <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
    
    <TD class="lblText" width="10%">Debit Account</TD>
    
    <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" class="textBox" NAME="debtAcc" id="debtAcc" disabled></TD>
  </TR>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. What exactly is happening and what should be happening? Also I strongly suggest you use proper HTML (consolidate on lowercase tags and attribute names and externalise the inline css attributes in a stylesheet)

Comment: HTML is lowercase no need for uppercase.This is Javascript no Java so you can remove tag